# iPhone calendar sync with Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, iphone, synchronization

I have an iPhone user that just recently noticed that his iPhone calendar changes are now overwriting any changes made in Outlook.  I checked and didn't see any config settings on the iPhone for whether the device or Exchange "wins".  Does anyone know where this might be configured?

Answer (score 2):

Last change wins, generally.

There are two scenarios I can think of here based on the wording of your question - which one are you referring to:

1. User makes change on Outlook, iPhone does not sync for whatever reason, iPhone's non-changed item then overwrites the changed item in Outlook.
2. User makes change on Outlook.  User makes different change on iPhone.  iPhone item overwrites Outlook.

If it's 1, that's an issue.  If it's 2, that's expected behavior.  Can you clarify further?

Comment: Sorry, he had added 4 new appointments throughout one day, that evening he noticed they weren't on his iPhone.  The following morning he said they were also missing from his Outlook.  Everything previously entered was still there, it only affected those that were entered on that day.  Today we did some testing and found that when we entered info into an existing appointment in his Outlook, it didn't update to the phone.  But when we updated the same item in the phone, it did change in Outlook.  Also, new appointments now seem to be syncing ok today.

Comment: If you're not experiencing an issue with other users, that's probably an iPhone issue rather than an Exchange one.  I would update his iPhone to the latest iOS release, delete his Exchange account on the phone, then recreate and watch the sync.  It's also possible you're having issues between syncing over 3/4G and wireless depending on your Exchange and DNS settings, but I would expect that to affect more users than just him.

Comment: Thanks for commenting - I really appreciate it.  I haven't checked what release his iOS is at, so I will check that and update accordingly, again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking time synchronization on the phone and on the server.